# How to rotate a matrix by one element anti clockwise ,n times ,using C or in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, rotation

If I give a matrix

```
a=[[1,2,3,4],
   [5,6,7,8],
   [9,10,11,12],
   [13,14,15,16]]
```

a 4*4 matrix. I want to rotate this matrix by one element of each layer anticlockwise. That is the result should be

```
a=[[2,3,4,8],
  [1,7,11,12],
  [5,6,10,16],
  [9,13,14,15]]
```

The outer elements rotate by one element and the inside 2*2 matrix also rotates by one element. Attempts have been made but unsuccessful. I didn't put the failed code. Moreover, the idea to post this as a question is that experts here would provide close to optimal solutions/ideas.The ideas are requested for the python language, just to clarify.

[Matrix Rotation Visualization][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXOd3.png

Comment: By writing proper code, compiling and executing. If you have some code you wrote and not working, please post it.

Comment: I haven't written any code of my own nor do I have anybody's. I am implementing this problem in python so I am looking for a way/logic in which this problem can be solved in python.

Comment: @Eswar -- How do you want to represent the matrix in python?  Can you use `numpy`?

Comment: @Eswar - If you want python, don't ask for `c` :-)

Comment: Moreover I am looking for generic solutions, not specific to 4*4. In python I've tried with functions like fliplr, flipud, swapaxes, rotateaxis, moveaxis, rot90 and various combinations of these functions and was unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this apparently is a request for code without own effort.

Comment: No there have been attempts made to solve this problem. But because I wasn't able to get it within a limited time, I have put up this question. Help me solve it.

Comment: @12345 - so you are not interested in a solution for `c`? If that is the case, please fix your title

Answer (score 1):

No need to make things complicated.

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,10,11,12],
     [13,14,15,16]]

a = [[a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3],a[1][3]],
     [a[0][0],a[1][2],a[2][2],a[2][3]],
     [a[1][0],a[1][1],a[2][1],a[3][3]],
     [a[2][0],a[3][0],a[3][1],a[3][2]]]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 8], [1, 7, 11, 12], [5, 6, 10, 16], [9, 13, 14, 15]]
```

But, if you must, a general solution (almost in-place):

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,10,11,12],
     [13,14,15,16]]

g = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],
     [7,8,9,10,11,12],
     [13,14,15,16,17,18],
     [19,20,21,22,23,24],
     [25,26,27,28,29,30],
     [31,32,33,34,35,36]]

def rotate_ring(matrix, offset):
    dim = len(matrix[0])
    last_element = matrix[offset][offset]
    for j in range(1+offset, dim-offset):
        matrix[offset][j-1] = matrix[offset][j]
    matrix[offset][dim-1-offset] = matrix[1+offset][dim-1-offset]
    for i in range(1+offset, dim-offset):
        matrix[i-1][dim-1-offset] = matrix[i][dim-1-offset]
    matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-1-offset] = matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-2-offset]
    for j in range(1+offset, dim-offset):
        matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-j] = matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-j-1]
    matrix[dim-1-offset][offset] = matrix[dim-2-offset][offset]
    for i in range(1+offset, dim-offset):
        matrix[dim-i][offset] = matrix[dim-i-1][offset]
    matrix[1+offset][offset] = last_element

def rotate_matrix(matrix):
    dim = len(matrix[0])
    for offset in range(0, int(dim/2)):
        rotate_ring(matrix, offset)

rotate_matrix(a)
rotate_matrix(g)

print(a)
print(g)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 8], [1, 7, 11, 12], [5, 6, 10, 16], [9, 13, 14, 15]]
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12], [1, 9, 10, 11, 17, 18], [7, 8, 16, 22, 23, 24], [13, 14, 15, 21, 29, 30], [19, 20, 26, 27, 28, 36], [25, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]
```

Comment: This is not a general solution. It is fixed to a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Question was not for a general solution, but a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: 4x4 was an example, clearly.

Comment: I really LoL when I saw you solution, really got imagination! But you better modify you solution so that it work for more general cases, like `2x2` or `16x16`?

Comment: Please show the example for a 8*8 matrix! I'd really like to see that all written manually.

Comment: You are given a 2D matrix, aa, of dimension M×N and a positive integer R. You have to rotate the matrix R times and print the resultant matrix. Rotation should be in anti-clockwise direction.

It is guaranteed that the minimum of MM and NN will be even.

Comment: General solution for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that makes clockwise rotation. Seems easy to swap left and right variables and take what you want

```
# Function to rotate a matrix
def rotateMatrix(mat):

    if not len(mat):
        return

    """
        top : starting row index
        bottom : ending row index
        left : starting column index
        right : ending column index
    """

    top = 0
    bottom = len(mat)-1

    left = 0
    right = len(mat[0])-1

    while left < right and top < bottom:

        # Store the first element of next row,
        # this element will replace first element of
        # current row
        prev = mat[top+1][left]

        # Move elements of top row one step right
        for i in range(left, right+1):
            curr = mat[top][i]
            mat[top][i] = prev
            prev = curr

        top += 1

        # Move elements of rightmost column one step downwards
        for i in range(top, bottom+1):
            curr = mat[i][right]
            mat[i][right] = prev
            prev = curr

        right -= 1

        # Move elements of bottom row one step left
        for i in range(right, left-1, -1):
            curr = mat[bottom][i]
            mat[bottom][i] = prev
            prev = curr

        bottom -= 1

        # Move elements of leftmost column one step upwards
        for i in range(bottom, top-1, -1):
            curr = mat[i][left]
            mat[i][left] = prev
            prev = curr

        left += 1

    return mat
```

Its Python. Import numpy and then make the table:

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]], int)
```

Make rotation and call the function rotateMatrix() :

```
m1=rotateMatrix(mat)
print m1
```

Hope it helps

code source :http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-matrix-elements/

Comment: Thank you. This code is working for the clockwise. I will do the needful to achieve my purpose.